# How to make requests to Web Api protected by Azure AD authorization with CURL or ARC

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, active-directory, oauth-2.0

I have a Web Api (just a result of the VS wizard with Azure AD authorization option turned on). I want to test this api directly, not using Azure API Management Portal or anything else. Particularly I want to use Advanced REST Client (often called ARC: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo), but any web client will suite me, for example curl.

Could somebody go through all the necessary steps to perform a proper authorization or recommend a good resource on this topic?

I expect all the work to be done manually, not using any tools except my browser and curl or arc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the request to the web API which protected by Azure AD, we need to get the access token through OAuth 2.0. After we create the web API project by Visual Studio, we still need to register an app on Azure portal which used to call the Web API.

For example, the Azure AD created an app **active-directory-webapi** for me when I create the web API project **active-directory-webapi** using the Visual Studio wizard with Azure AD authentication.

Then I open the Azure AD portal though this [link](https://manage.windowsazure.com/) and register an web application named as **active-directory-webapi-client**.  Since it is a web application, we need to generate an secret for it. And to use call the web API, we need to add the **web api application** to grant the permission for it. Here is an figure for basic information for app I register it manually:
[image]

Then we can use OAuth 2.0 require the token for this app:

```
Get: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={clientId in figure }&redirect_uri={redirect Url in figure}
```

Then we need to input the username/password and get the OAuth code in the Url. And we can get the token through the OAuth code by request below:

```
POST: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/token
client_id={client_id in figure}&client_secret{secret in figure}&code={OAuth code in the previews request}&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri={ redirect Url in figure }&resource={ it as the Audience in the web.config of web API project}
```

At last, we can call the web API use the token from request above:

```
Get: https://localhost:44305/api/values
authorization: bearer {accessToken}
```

More  detail about OAuth 2.0 authorization flow you can refer [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code/).